# Exporting Vaadin 14 application with addons throws BeanInstantationException

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin14

I'm trying to export a Vaadin 14 application that uses an addon (autocomplete addon) and the exported application seems to miss the addon, but I'm failing to understand what I'm doing wrong when exporting. Launching it from inside eclipse works perfectly.

First I was trying to export the application with 'mvn clean package -Pproduction', but even if the application seemed to be working with no errors in the java console, I was getting them in the browser console (TypeError: i.register is not a function). The application seemed to load, but seems to be missing both the addon and some styles.

From inside the IDE

[image: Application as seen when launched inside IDE]

From outside the IDE
[image: Application when launched from outside the IDE]

I tried then to launch it with a goal I found on the pom (clean package -Dvaadin.productionMode) and got a different error, this time on console

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'org.test.MainView':
>   Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.test.MainView]: Constructor threw
>   exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Couldn't find the definition of the element with tag
>   'vcf-autocomplete' in any template file declared using '@JsModule'
>   annotations. Check the availability of the template files in your WAR
>   file or provide alternative implementation of the method
>   getTemplateContent() which should return an element representing the
>   content of the template file

While the explanation seems detailed, I'm not sure how to proceed, as I'm just using an addon and error text seems to imply that something is missing with the addon.

If I generate the application with *clean package -Pproduction -Dvaadin.productionMode* I get same behavior as first one (error in console *TypeError: i.register is not a function*)

What I'm missing to get the addon exported/compiled into the application?

Comment: Please add `MainView` class to the question.

Comment: Error "Couldn't find the definition of the element with tag 'vcf-autocomplete'" indicates that creation of the front end bundle has not gone right, since the client implementation of component is missing.

Comment: Error "TypeError: i.register is not a function" indicates that Polymer library is missing in frontend, but template declaring element is executed. Error happens when element is being registered.

Comment: Since it is Spring application, you should define production mode to be true in application.properties.